# How to include related resource with Django Rest Framework JSON API?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, json-api

I am using [Django Rest Framework JSON API](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api) to create a REST API. I am trying quite simply to include a related resource (2nd degree relation) but Django keeps responding with the error:

```
This endpoint does not support the include parameter for path...
```

The structure is something like this:

```
# models:

class Household(models.Model):
  ...

class HouseholdMember(models.Model):
  household = models.ForeignKey(Household)
  ...

class Subscription(models.Model):
  subscriber = models.ForeignKey(HouseholdMember)
  ...

# serializers

from rest_framework_json_api import serializers

class SubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Subscription
```

I would like to be able to make a request like this: `http://example.com/api/subscriptions?include=subscriber.household` to be able to group subscriptions by household. However, I simply cannot find out how to do this. [I know](http://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.1/usage.html#related-fields) I need to play around with `ResourceRelatedField` but I'm missing something or too much of a newbie to understand how this works. Any help?

Comment: json api is under appreciated. Haven't seen enough mentions of declarative entity traversal via query params in apis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, perhaps I was missing something obvious (because this wasn't mentioned in the documentation), but if you look at the [`serializers.py`](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api/blob/develop/example/serializers.py#L34)file in the example directory of the source of Django Rest Framework JSON API, it looks like you need to have a variable called `included_serializers` to do what I wanted. For my example, here's what you would need:

```
# models:

class Household(models.Model):
  ...

class HouseholdMember(models.Model):
  household = models.ForeignKey(Household)
  ...

class Subscription(models.Model):
  subscriber = models.ForeignKey(HouseholdMember)
  ...

# serializers

from rest_framework_json_api import serializers

class HouseholdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Household

class HouseholdMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  included_serializers = {
    'household': HouseholdSerializer
  }

  class Meta:
    model = HouseholdMember

class SubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  included_serializers = {
    'subscriber': SubscriberSerializer
  }

  class Meta:
    model = Subscription
```